# problem with placing a figure on the bottom of the chapter page

Tags: floats, report

I cannot place my figure on the bottom of the first page of the chapter. Instead, it's placed on the bottom of the next page. In the main file I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}   %12 point font for Times New Roman
\usepackage{graphicx}  %for images and plots
\begin{document}
\input{chapter1.tex}
\end{document}
```

In the chapter1.tex, I have:

```
\chapter{chapter1}
some text
%
\begin{figure}[!b]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.85\linewidth]{figures/FIG1_1}
\end{figure}
%
```

I have also tried to change the latex defaults on floats but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions please?

Comment: How much content do you have in `chapter1.tex`?

Comment: @Werner, it is 5 pages so far.

Comment: Well, the entire `chapter1.tex` is processed (which sets 5 pages) and then it reads your `figure` environment. Of course there would be no way for it to now suddenly go back and insert it on the first page of the chapter. Do you have access to place the `figure` environment inside `chapter1.tex` immediately after `\chapter`?

Comment: @Werner I edited the post. I was placing the figure command inside the chapter1.tex. After I moved the figure right after \chapter, it works as I want. Thank you. I did not quite understand why it was putting the figure on the bottom of the second page?

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 7):

While TeX does some funny business in placing floats, it's mostly sequential in its transition from input to output.

If the placement of

```
\begin{figure}[!b]
  % Your figure here
\end{figure}
```

is too far from the beginning of `\chapter`, it'll necessary flow over to a later page. Since floats are allowed at the bottom of a `\chapter` page (in general), the best option would be to place the `figure` code immediately after `\chapter{<title>}`.

The only reason why the `figure` might not end up at the bottom may be because it is too large or placed too late in the code.

Answer (score -1):

Use

\begin{figure}[h]

% Your figure here

\end{figure}

this one works

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document which we can test your suggestion and than see if it really solve the OP problems. So far your answer is vague ...